# R how to obtain the mean of previous values depending on a second column with data in long format

Tags: r, long-integer, mixed-models

I prepared a reproducible example with an example of dataset here:

```
patient <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)

month <- rep (1:10, 2)

fev1 <- c(58, NA, NA, NA, 57, NA, NA, NA, NA, 60, NA, NA, NA, NA, 32, NA, NA, NA, NA, 40)

adherence <- c (30, 32, 34, 36, 34, 32, 30, 34, 32, 36, 70, 65, 75, 70, 70, 55, 50, 65, 70, 70)

data <- tibble(patient, month, fev1, adherence)
data
```

I would like to obtain a 5th column, called mean adherence, which for each fev1 value which is not NA, would provide the mean adherence of the previous values since the last fev1 value, including the adherence value corresponding to the preceding fev1 value, and excluding the adherence value corresponding to the current fev1 value, and this for each patient id.

For example, for patient 1, at month 5, for fev1 = 57, it would compute the mean of (30, 32, 34, 36); then, for fev1 = 60, it would compute the mean of (34, 32, 30, 34, 32)

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create a grouping variable based on the NA values in fev1, and then get the `mean` by group

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(patient) %>% 
  mutate(lagadher = lag(adherence), 
      grp = lag(cumsum(!is.na(fev1)))) %>%
  group_by(grp, .add = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Mean_adhere = mean(lagadher) * NA^(is.na(fev1))) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-grp, -lagadher)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 20 × 5
   patient month  fev1 adherence Mean_adhere
     <dbl> <int> <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
 1       1     1    58        30        NA  
 2       1     2    NA        32        NA  
 3       1     3    NA        34        NA  
 4       1     4    NA        36        NA  
 5       1     5    57        34        33  
 6       1     6    NA        32        NA  
 7       1     7    NA        30        NA  
 8       1     8    NA        34        NA  
 9       1     9    NA        32        NA  
10       1    10    60        36        32.4
11       2     1    NA        70        NA  
12       2     2    NA        65        NA  
13       2     3    NA        75        NA  
14       2     4    NA        70        NA  
15       2     5    32        70        70  
16       2     6    NA        55        NA  
17       2     7    NA        50        NA  
18       2     8    NA        65        NA  
19       2     9    NA        70        NA  
20       2    10    40        70        62
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However if I am correct this excludes the adherence value corresponding to the preceding fev1 value, and includes the adherence value corresponding to the current fev1 value. I would like to do the reverse, i.e. include the adherence value corresponding to the preceding fev1 value, and exclude the adherence value corresponding to the current fev1 value. Do you see how we can obtain that ?

Comment: @David Is the update correct.  `mean(c(30, 32, 34, 36))
[1] 33` and `mean(c(34, 32, 30, 34, 32))#
[1] 32.4`